# Optimization Resourcepool Anylogic

Tags: optimization, simulation, anylogic

[image]

Hi there! Could you help and guide me on the objective of optimizing the resource pool? I have 2 shifts in each resource pool. How do I fill this objective? In AnyLogic there is one example but so difficult to understand but I need this simple solution, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to define some objective of your optimization experiment, for example optimizing the production output of the model.

You can access the variables of the object you are running using `root.`

See simple example below.

[image]

Hit the Create default UI button when done to create some default UI and then run the Optimization experiment..

Comment: I have error Description: productionOutput cannot be resolved or is not a field. How to deal with that? please help me

Comment: productionOutput is just from my example - use what ever you have in your model or name the variable you want to optimize  productionOutput